# MonoTouch - Create UI Without Xib

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I looked at the Monotouch.dialog stuff and it's pretty awesome. However, it has some limitations. I was hoping to be able to create my app without having to use Xib files, but I'm not sure how to do that. Without MonoTouch dialog and xib files.... I don't know any other way.

Could anyone point in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't know how to do this for the longest time, but it's simpler than you would think! Just add a regular C# class (you don't need to use any of the special templates), import the MonoTouch.Foundation and MonoTouch.UIKit namespaces, and make your new class a subclass of UIViewController.

It's that simple! You'll want to override the usual methods like ViewDidLoad, but that should be enough to get you started. As far as implementing a UI without using a .xib, just create everything programatically, set the frame, and add it to the view (and of course customize it with properties/methods and such)!

You would set it up something like:

```
// Table setup
var VersesTable = new UITableView ()
{
    Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height - 93),
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage (Images.BackgroundTexture),
};
View.AddSubview (VersesTable);
```

The hardest part of doing this is getting the frame and everything setup (imo).

There is also some [real-life code](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation/blob/master/TweetStation/Dialogs/Settings.cs) of not using .xibs and using MonoTouch.Dialog at the Github page for [TweetStation](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation). https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation/blob/master/TweetStation/Dialogs/Settings.cs

In the Xamarin Forums, there is a [post](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1164/ios-layout-in-c) detailing some more examples of using purely C# code (no .xibs) that is very helpful!

Comment: Great answer. I didn't want to use `MonoTouch.Dialog` on one screen because I had images that had to be built like a pyramid and that's pretty difficult with MTD compared to just building it from code. I was overthinking this way too much. I actually inherited the `UIViewController` and overrode the base methods like you talked about. then just built the elements out like you did and added them to the view. I think the hardest part is positioning as well... So I used `Interface Builder` to get the positioning. I then turned those positions into a percentage of the screen size.

Comment: If anyone wonders whether or not to do it through code or IB... I prefer code. Much easier than bouncing between both. I also used percentages for positioning and size after getting the position right so that it would work universally (ipad/iphone)

Comment: BRodgers, I completely agree! With Interface Builder there is a ton of ambuigity (you really have no idea what is going on), but with code approach, you really can see exactly what is happening.

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion after starting with storyboards. Another issue with xib is debugging. You get no meaningful error message and can't step though the transformation of xib files. I have found it is easier to write flexible, flowing UI in code behind that will accommodate all iOS device window sizes in one step. I would be good to see a simple hello world monotouch example of a couple of screens navigating back and forth. Just need a pointer on how to lay that out to get started correctly.

Comment: Hi RandallTo, I actually have some sample code at https://github.com/pierceboggan/VersesApp/ that shows some layout code (100% C# UI). Some is not best-practice, but it will help you to get the idea!